# Scan face without show camera app

Tags: android

Is this possible to scan face without show camera app to user ?

I want to create an app which get the photo without open the camera app. We can't see the camera app.

Comment: without rooting, then prolly not. do you realize the grave security implications of what you want to do if people can just code applications that can take your photo without you knowing it's being taken?

Comment: i will say to people with toast or something like that "We are scaning your face now ." it is not my aim that stole  their photos .i want to take their instant  photos with their permission.it is only my aim.

Comment: That's the thing. Even if that isn't your intention, allowing this allows other people to steal photos of their users.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I understand what you said . I should use the users' camera app for their security.

Comment: Just follow the official tutorial for making an app. using the camera at [https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera) or study the newer Camera API at [https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html)

Comment: Maybe someone can write a proper answer to you. I haven't tried out those APIs myself so I decided just to add a comment.